# How to Automate Several Piezo Actuators

Tags: automation, labview

So i am working on a project that involves three different piezo actuators, and a stage with multiple holes in it. The piezos apply movement to whatever is coincident with it on the order of nanometers (nm) and I wish to apply them simultaneously as needed. The Piezos I have (Nano PZ) are  essentially needed to move a mini stage on a microscope in the x-y plane. The third piezo (NPA series) allows me to move the stage in the z axis, but this has already been programmed by someone, so I am now concerned with writing code in LabVIEW to move the x and y axis piezos.

How this should all play out is that once I execute my program to run diagnostics on the first hole in the stage the code will then tell the piezos to move on to the next whole in the stage, and then the next one, and etc until all the holes in the n by m matrix of holes has undergone diagnostics.

This is my first time using LabVIEW but has been recommended to me because of its "ease of use" in that the piezo drivers and related software is in LabVIEW. If my explanation is too vague I'd be more than happy to clarify but this is essentially what I need help with.

Comment: What's your specific question? What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I'm still trying to learn LabVIEW. I want to be able to program the piezos (one that supplies translation in the x-axis and one for the y-axis) so that I don't have to manually move my stage every time I want to run diagnostics on each hole.

Comment: Then it doesn't sound as if you have a question for Stack Overflow yet.

Comment: Which controller do you have for the NanoPZ?

Comment: The PZC200 Hand-held controller for PZA12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newport provides a basic [Labview driver for PZC200 controller](ftp://download.newport.com/MotionControl/Current/MotionControllers/PZC200/Software/Labview%20Drivers/), that can be useful as a starting point.
As for the list of commands, you'll find them in the [User Manual](ftp://download.newport.com/MotionControl/Current/MotionControllers/PZC200/Manual/NanoPZ.pdf)

Comment: Thanks marco. I knew there was a driver for it but I couldn't find it online. Hopefully I'll be able to come up with something useful and I'll post it if I do.